# Why does results are different when relational operators means the same?

Tags: c++, while-loop, operators

For clarification, let's consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    short int i; // declaration
    short int value;
    short int sum;

    i = value = sum = 0; // initialization

    std::cout << "Enter a value: ";
    std::cin >> value;

    while (i != value) { // ### here's the confusion ###
        sum += i;
        i++;
    }

    std::cout << "Total sum: " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Look at the `while (i != value)`, when this expression is given, the results shows `Total sum: 45` whereas if we put `while (i <= value)`, it shows `Total sum: 55`. (Input's given `10` for example)

Here, the confusion is, when should we use `!=` and `<=` **or** `>=` operations in loops, any specific condition?

According to [TutorialsPoint's Operators Reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_operators.htm)

- it tells that `!=` (returns `true` used when two operands are unequal).
- `<=` (returns `true` when used when we need to ensure if the first operand is lesser than or equal to second).

It was expected to get no difference in output, but something's misunderstood.

Comment: Step through in a debugger and find the exact comparison where the execution splits from what you expect.

Comment: Your bullet points *clearly* show that they are *not* equivalent. What happens when `i=5`, and `num=5`?

Comment: BTW, there is no reason to use `short int`.  Usually the `int` type is the size of a processors register and processors are optimized for that data size.  For example, a `short` *can* be 16 bits which would be annoying for a processor that only fetches 32-bits.  If you want 16-bit quantities, then use `uint16_t` or `int16_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This while loop

```
while (i != value)
```

does not include the iteration when i is equal to value because in this case the condition i != value evaluates to false.

This while loop

```
while (i <= value)
```

includes the iteration when i is equal to value because in this case the condition i <= value evaluates to true.

In fact the first condition can be rewritten the following way (provided that initially i is less than value)

```
while ( i < value )
```

Now compare it with the condition in the second loop that in turn can be rewritten like

```
while ( i < value || i == value )
```

That is you have two different conditions.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
while( i <= value)
```

the last iteration is with `i == value`. With

```
while ( i != value)
```

The body of the loop will not be executed when `i == value`. That is the reason you observe the difference.

This is a good chance to learn how to use a debugger. And/Or realize that your example is already too complicated to directly see what is going on. You would have spotted the difference more easily with

```
int i = 0;
int value = 5;
while ( i != value) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
i = 0;
while ( i <= value) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
```